# How to sort by job title in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have a class called `Shareholder` and each `Shareholder` can have one of 4 job titles: president, vice_president, secretary, or treasurer (in that order).

I would like to sort a list of shareholders by their job title, but I don't know how to do this other than by making this horrible cmp function like so:

```
def shareholder_title_sort(s1, s2):
    if s1.is_president: return -1
    elif s2.is_president: return 1
    elif s1.is_vice_president: return -1
    elif s2.is_vice_president: return 1
    elif s1.is_secretary: return -1
    elif s2.is_secretary: return 1
    elif s1.is_treasurer: return -1
    elif s2.is_treasurer: return 1
    else: return 0
```

And using it like this:

```
sorted(list(shareholders), cmp=shareholder_title_sort)
```

Here is the `Shareholder` class:

```
SHAREHOLDER_TITLE = (
    ("P", "President",),
    ("S", "Secretary",),
    ("T", "Treasurer",),
    ("V", "Vice President",),
)

class Shareholder(AuditModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    primary_title = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHAREHOLDER_TITLE)
    secondary_title = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHAREHOLDER_TITLE)

    @property
    def is_president(self):
        return self.primary_title == 'P' or self.secondary_title == 'P'

    @property
    def is_vice_president(self):
        return self.primary_title == 'V' or self.secondary_title == 'V'

    @property
    def is_secretary(self):
        return self.primary_title == 'S' or self.secondary_title == 'S'

    @property
    def is_treasurer(self):
        return self.primary_title == 'T' or self.secondary_title == 'T'
```

What is a more elegant way to do this in Python 2?

Comment: I think the elegant way would be to not use booleans to indicate a title, but a "title" property with a string value. Then shareholders only need 1 property instead of as many as there are jobs

Comment: Agreed, and we actually do. The problem is we use two attributes: `primary_title` and `secondary_title`, and `is_{title}` are properties that abstract away whether its their primary or secondary title.

Comment: I added the `Shareholder` class. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @grantmcconnaughey: you can still use a mapping with that: `min(role_order[s.primary_title], role_order[s.secondary_title])` will sort them by their highest ranking role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map the types to numbers, use that in a `key` sort:

```
def sort_by_role(s):
    if s.is_president: return 0
    if s.is_vice_president: return 1
    if s.is_secretary: return 2
    if s.is_treasurer: return 3
    return 4  # sort the rest at the end.

sorted(shareholders, key=sort_by_role)
```

If there is a 'role' attribute, you could use that in a dictionary mapping instead, however:

```
role_order = {r[0]: i for i, r in enumerate(SHAREHOLDER_TITLE)}
best_role = lambda s: min(role_order[s.primary_rank], role_order[s.secondary_rank])
sorted(shareholders, key=best_role)
```

The dictionary comprehension produces a mapping from ranking letter to index (so `P` maps to `0`). The `best_role` finds a shareholder's 'highest' ranking (lowest index number) based on their primary or secondary role.

This does assume your `SHAREHOLDER_TITLE` sequence is sorted in preference order. If not, just produce a manual mapping; e.g. `{'P': 0, 'V': 1, 'S': 2, 'T': 3}`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution like that shown below may help. The goal in the answer's code was to make the objects sortable without the need for a key. Other comparison operators may be required depending on what sorting mechanism is being used.

```
TITLES = {'President': 'P', 'Vice President': 'V',
          'Secretary': 'S', 'Treasurer': 'T'}
CHOICES = tuple((b, a) for a, b in TITLES.items())


class Shareholder(AuditModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    primary_title = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)
    secondary_title = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def is_president(self):
        return self.__has_title('President')

    @property
    def is_vice_president(self):
        return self.__has_title('Vice President')

    @property
    def is_secretary(self):
        return self.__has_title('Secretary')

    @property
    def is_treasurer(self):
        return self.__has_title('Treasurer')

    def __has_title(self, title):
        return TITLES[title] in {self.primary_title, self.secondary_title}

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.__order < other.__order

    @property
    def __order(self):
        if self.is_president:
            return 0
        if self.is_vice_president:
            return 1
        if self.is_secretary:
            return 2
        if self.is_treasurer:
            return 3
        return 4
```